# Want an array formula for employees matching a selected name without added blank spaces? Want to show what's been entered already without gaps

Tags: arrays, database, match, multiple-columns

K1 is the selected employee name, and A2:A22 is the location of the names with the accompanying data that I want to show to the right of it. However, because the database will grow significantly over time, I just want to show the selected employee without all the extra spaces.

This is a formula that I'm currently using, but I am toying with a couple others yielding similar results.
=IF(K1=A2:A22,Table8[[Emp Name]:[Month]],"")

This is another that shows basically the same thing.
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Table8[Emp Name],K1)),Table8[[Emp Name]:[Month]],"")

It gives me results, but is not ideal as my database of entries continues to grow.

Comment: I figured it out using the filter function. It does exactly what I need it to. It filters the names to a selected employee, and filters the months of entries to limit it and only show the months I want it to.

=FILTER(Table8[[Emp Name]:[Month]],(Table8[Emp Name]=$C$15)*(Table8[Month]>(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1)),"No Data")